# How to hide an empty not unique table column with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I've got a table with alot of columns that shows the difference between two products. Many of them are empty and I don't need those with no difference to the first one. I've came up with this code:

```js
$('#product_diff tr').each(function(){
    let _hide = true;
    const values = []
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).html().trim() !== ''){
            _hide = false
        }
        values.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
    
    const allEqual = arr => arr.every( v => v === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(values) === true ) {
        _hide = true
    }
    console.log(_hide)
    if(_hide){
        $(this).find('td').hide()
    }
});
```

My table looks like this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="diffTitle">...</th>
        <th scope="col">1</th>
        <th scope="col">2</th>
        <th scope="col">3</th>
        <th scope="col">4</th>
        <th scope="col">5</th>
        <th scope="col">6</th>
        <th scope="col">7</th>
        <th scope="col">8</th>
        <th scope="col">9</th>
        <th scope="col">10</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to hide every `<td>` that is empty or is the same as all the other values in the same column. Does anyone know how to fix my code to get this to work?

jsfiddle-example: https://jsfiddle.net/y5f7u8d2/

Comment: How you print table? and what you mean for _hide_ ? because if you delete part of td table will print weird

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: As you can see [link](https://ibb.co/Yp0HJnv) the is result of your code, it's not regular table.

Comment: It should just hide those columns which are empty in every tr so the entire column gets hidden

Comment: I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fned8vmk) real quick, as you can see in this example, I want to hide column 2,3,4 and 7 since all of its content is empty

Answer (score 0):

I create an script for that see:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var columns = $("#mytable > tbody > tr:first > td").length;
  for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    if ($("#mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(" + i + ")").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() != '';
    }).length == 0) {
      $("#mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(" + i + "), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(" + i + ")").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="mytable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="diffTitle">...</th>
        <th scope="col">1</th>
        <th scope="col">2</th>
        <th scope="col">3</th>
        <th scope="col">4</th>
        <th scope="col">5</th>
        <th scope="col">6</th>
        <th scope="col">7</th>
        <th scope="col">8</th>
        <th scope="col">9</th>
        <th scope="col">10</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I loop td for see if all is empty or not.

Comment: I don't really know why but your code does not work for me somehow.. It does hide one field but not the empty ones

Comment: post a snippet with that i will see.